# Insert sObject share for task that the user doesn't own

Tags: apex, sharing, sobject

As a regular user (not system administrator) is it possible to create a share for a object that I'm not the owner of in APEX?

Or will the DML statement throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible either through a Class that uses "without sharing" or an Apex Trigger. These will function no matter who does the update. A class that uses "with sharing" will have a problem, though.

Quick warning: I've never deal with TaskShares, and I never make bets on whether Tasks will behave like normal objects.

Comment: Ok I'll check it out!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy just checked it out and it looks like this was the correct way to go.